# Java Bean Validation number formatting issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, bean-validation

I am struggling with Bean Validation to validate a Double attribute.

My application uses AngularJS with Java EE (JAX-RS / JAXB) for the backend.

My class looks like:

```java
public class MyClass {

  @NotNull
  Double value;

  // empty constructor, getters, setters

}
```

If I either send to the server, the JSON representation of MyClass as :

```
{ value: '' }
```

Or

```
{ value: '456q' }
```

I end up with a validation constraint violation for value "must not be null".

I would have liked a validation constraint for type formatting issue for the second JSON representation.

Is there any way to do it beside client side validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your JSON is sent as string, then casted as Double (using something like `Double.valueOf("456q")`), and javax.validation does not have the knowledge of that string.

However, it is still checked as a number (null is returned in invalid case).

If you really want to do a format check, then you should probably store the value as a String, and cast it as a Double when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The value that you are sending are of string type. Try sending

```
{ value: 456 }
```

Now it's a number and validation should work fine.